# How to secure 2 endpoints in Spring, one with Basic Auth and the second one with OAuth?

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, oauth

I'm trying to secure 3 endpoints. /test1 with basic auth and /test2, test3 with ouath. I'm trying to do that with multiple httpsecurity, like in many examples. However this does not work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity // (proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SecurityConfigOauth {
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChainOauth(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .oauth2Login( oauth2Login -> {oauth2Login.loginPage("/test1");});

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChainHTTPBasic(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers("/test2/**", "/test3/**").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver pkceResolver(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver resolver = new
                DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(clientRegistrationRepository,
                OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI);
        resolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestCustomizers.withPkce());
        return resolver;
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("test").password("test").roles("first")
                .and()
                .withUser("test").password("test").roles("second");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to secure 3 endpoints with basic auth and oauth.

Answer (score 0):

To work with multiple SecurityFilterChain beans you should add a filter with the method `HttpSecurity.securityMatcher()`. Like this:

```java
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainOauth2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .securityMatcher("/test1/**")
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2Login((oauth2Login) -> oauth2Login
            .userInfoEndpoint((userInfo) -> userInfo
                .userAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthoritiesMapper())
            )
        );
    return http.build();
}
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainDefault(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
            .requestMatchers("/test2/**", "/test3/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        )
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

Please mind the @Order annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
Unfortunately it doesn't work. It redirects me to this: [Redirect 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bmAE.png)

But if I use this code It's almost working, I can login:

```
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChainOauth(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .securityMatcher("/test1/**")
            .oauth2Login((oauth2Login) -> oauth2Login
                    .userInfoEndpoint((userInfo) -> userInfo
                            .userAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthoritiesMapper())
                    ))
                    .oauth2Login( oauth2Login -> {oauth2Login.loginPage("/test1");});

    return http.build();
}
```

I get stuck on the redirect: [Redirect 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMKCa.png)

Any ideas ?